# Unable to use undeclared variable

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

```
DECLARE @LINKEDSERVER VARCHAR(20)= 'LS_CMT';
        DECLARE @ODS_DBNAME VARCHAR(20)= '';
        SET @ODS_DBNAME = DB_NAME();
        DECLARE @OCS_DBNAME VARCHAR(20)= '';
        SET @OCS_DBNAME = 'CMT' + SUBSTRING(@ODS_DBNAME, CHARINDEX('_', @ODS_DBNAME), LEN(@ODS_DBNAME))
SELECT * FROM @ODS_DBNAME.[dbo].CLI_LOCATIONS
```

Comment: You're right this isn't allowed - you can build the string first and then execute it with sp_executesql.

see
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for that purpose

```
DECLARE @LINKEDSERVER VARCHAR(20)= 'LS_CMT'; 
DECLARE @ODS_DBNAME VARCHAR(20)= ''; 
SET @ODS_DBNAME = DB_NAME(); 
DECLARE @OCS_DBNAME VARCHAR(20)= ''; 
SET @OCS_DBNAME = 'CMT'
                  + SUBSTRING(@ODS_DBNAME, CHARINDEX('_', @ODS_DBNAME), LEN(@ODS_DBNAME)) ;
 EXEC('SELECT * FROM ' + @ODS_DBNAME + '.[dbo].CLI_LOCATIONS');
```